Batch change color space in image textures
I am looking for a script which can batch change the settings in the image texture node. This is about using ACES in Blender.
I need this script to:

Batch change all the base color image textures from sRGB to Utility – sRGB – Texture.
Batch change all the other image textures, metallic, roughness, normal, displacement, etc from Non-Color to role_data.

Can anyone with scripting knowledge help please?

Currently I don't have ACES OCIO installed, so I can' try a fast answer, but Chat GPT is incredibly good at creating small Python Scripts for Blender like this.
